# Printing not working in WSL v1

Tags: software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the latest Windows-10 1909. Ubuntu in both cases is 18.04.

With Ubuntu as a VM printing works fine. Example  `ls -l | lpr`

With Ubuntu as a WSL BASH printing not so good. Complains no lpr command.

I would appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: WSL is not a complete Linux install. I have not tried to tried it, but here is what I found via Google search. [Printing with Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://www.scivision.dev/scanningprinting-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux/)

Comment: Seems like expected behavior: `lpr` does not work with WSL. However, CUPS does.